# How to use cross apply string split result to update a table in sql?

Tags: sql-server, split, cross-apply

I am trying to split a **column('categories') of a Table 'movies_titles'** which has string separated data values in it.

```
e.g:
ID title     categories
1  Movie A   Comedy, Drama, Romance
2  Movie B   Animation
3  Movie C   Documentary, Life changing
```

I want to split the comma delimited string and place each values in a separate rows and update the table

```
-- this query shows the splitted strings as I want it
SELECT *
FROM dbo.movies_titles
CROSS APPLY
string_split(categories, ',') 

O/P:
ID title     categories                   value
1  Movie A   Comedy, Drama, Romance       Comedy
1  Movie A   Comedy, Drama, Romance       Drama
1  Movie A   Comedy, Drama, Romance       Romance
2  Movie B   Animation                    Animation
3  Movie C   Documentary, Life changing   Documentary
3  Movie C   Documentary, Life changing   Life changing
```

I want to use UPDATE query to set the result obtained from **value** column. I just don't want to use SELECT query to view the result but permanently update the changes to the table. How do I achieve this in sql server?

Comment: and what  table do you want to update? Now for Movie A you have three values

Comment: I want to update the rows in the table like the output above. For example, If I apply  SELECT *
FROM dbo.movies_titles to view the data, it does not show any changes or updates. I want to be able to use the 'cross apply string_split' as part of UPDATE query not just SELECT it.

Comment: You can't UPDATE the source table and make it like the output, because number of rows in the output is more than number of rows in the source table and UPDATE will not change the number of rows. But you can use a second table and INSERT the output to it.

Comment: To get your desired results will require *several* steps. You'll first need to create intermediate results ie using a temp table, then *insert* new rows into the table, then update all rows with the individual category values.

Comment: @Stu Can be done in one step with `MERGE` from/to the same table, see my answer

Comment: Just insert and then delete the ones your don't want to keep. The presence of a comma is one way to know which ones that are.

Comment: @Charlieface yes thanks I overlooked you can use merge for that, I tend to steer clear of using it generally for the various bugs and edge cases it has.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to your intention creating new rows, because the update statement won't create the additional rows made by the split.

There can be issues if the ID column is unique, like a primary key, and there is the need to keep the title associated with that column.

I've created two scenarios on DB Fiddle, showing how you can do this using only one table as the question instructed, but a [better alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would be to save this information on another table.

This code on DB Fiddle: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=946c6ee3a621738612a48ea2219abff5)

```
--Assuming your table is something like this
create table movies_id_as_pk (
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    title varchar(200),
    categories varchar(200),
    category varchar(200)
)
--Or this
create table movies_other_pk (
    another_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    ID int,
    title varchar(200),
    categories varchar(200),
    category varchar(200)
)
--The example data
set identity_insert movies_id_as_pk on
insert into movies_id_as_pk (ID, title, categories) values
(1,  'Movie A',   'Comedy, Drama, Romance'),
(2,  'Movie B',   'Animation'),
(3,  'Movie C',   'Documentary, Life changing')
set identity_insert movies_id_as_pk off
insert into movies_other_pk (ID, title, categories)
    select ID, title, categories from movies_id_as_pk
```

```
--You can't update directly any of the tables, because as the result of the split
--have more rows than the table, it would just leave the first value found:
update m set category = rtrim(ltrim(s.value))
from movies_id_as_pk m
cross apply string_split(m.categories, ',') as s

update m set category = rtrim(ltrim(s.value))
from movies_other_pk m
cross apply string_split(m.categories, ',') as s

select * from movies_id_as_pk
select * from movies_other_pk
```

```
--What you can do is create the aditional rows, inserting them:
--First, let's undo what the last instructions have changed
update movies_id_as_pk set category=NULL
update movies_other_pk set category=NULL

--Then use inserts to create the rows with the categories split
insert into movies_id_as_pk (title, category)
    select m.title, rtrim(ltrim(s.value))
    from movies_id_as_pk m
    cross apply string_split(m.categories, ',') as s

insert into movies_other_pk (ID, title, category)
    select m.ID, m.title, rtrim(ltrim(s.value))
    from movies_other_pk m
    cross apply string_split(m.categories, ',') as s

select * from movies_id_as_pk
select * from movies_other_pk
```

Answer (score 0):

**It actually *is* possible to insert or update at the same time.** That is to say: we can update each row with a single `category`, then create new rows for the extra ones.

We can use `MERGE` for this. We can use the same table as source and target. We just need to split the source, then add a row-number partitioned per each original row. We then filter the `ON` clause to match only the first row.

```sql
WITH Source AS (
    SELECT
      m.ID,
      m.title,
      category = TRIM(cat.value),
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM movies m
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(m.categories, ',') cat
)
MERGE movies t
USING Source s
ON s.ID = t.ID AND s.rn = 1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET categories = s.category
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, title, categories)
  VALUES (s.ID, s.title, s.category)
;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45a39ca201b30ae0e76b05a80c66fbd7)

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this as a general solution though, because it appears you actually have other normalization problems to sort out first. You should really have separate tables for all this information:

- `Movie`
- `Category`
- `MovieCategory`